# cant get PercentRelativeLayout signed id onClick

Tags: android

Following is my layout and my java code.
As you can see I give  `PercentRelativeLayout` an id of `categori1`.
I specify the `onClick` handler as `filtre_kategori_ac_kapat`.
The problem is that when I try to log the view id I get a number that is not `categori1`. But if I give the Layout a tag then try to Log Tag value it is correct !!!

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/categori_height"
    android:background="@drawable/combo"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/categori1"
    android:onClick="filtre_kategori_ac_kapat"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
        android:text="@string/filtre_sehir"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/acik"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="10%"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        app:layout_marginRightPercent="5%"
        android:src="@drawable/categori_ok_kapali"
        android:id="@+id/categori1ok" />
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Following is the function that I use to trace it's id.

```
public void filtre_kategori_ac_kapat(View v) {
   Log.e("traced id",String.valueOf(v.getId()));
}
```

The result I got is `traced id: 2131492994`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the value of `categori1` in `R.java`

Somewhere in you R file you should find:

```
public static final class id {
    ...
    public static final int categori1 = 0x7f0c0082;
```

If you check

`v.getId() == R.id.categori1`

It should be true.

Comment: thanks for your answer but when I compare it in if block it return false that is whay I try to log value of id

Comment: What is the value of `categori1` in `R.java`?

Comment: public static final int categori1=0x7f0c0082;

Comment: Well 0x7f0c0082 (hex) = 2131492994 (decimal) so it should be equal. That's odd. What's the original code you're trying to run?

Comment: it is filter menu when user click one it has to open a drop down menu

Comment: You're checking for `categori2` instead of `categori1`

Comment: categori3 is a onether percentRelativeLayout that have same onclick listener main problem is that v.getId() returns hex or decimal value